# How to empty a textbox, textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $contact_title = $('#contact_title').val();
var $contact_summary = $('#bbcode').val();
```

I retreive a text area and text field then I do this:

```
$contact_title.val('');
$contact_summary.val('');
```

Nnone of them get emptied

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Title:</td>
            <td>
                <input name="title" type="text" style="width:710px" id="contact_title" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">Message:</td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="request" cols="30" rows="20" id="bbcode"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" >
                <input name="send" type="button" onClick="clicked()" value="Send" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the element in your variable and not the value.

So, your code should be:

```
var $contact_summary = $('#bbcode');
$contact_summary.val('');
```

Btw, it's a good practice to use [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and bind your click event outside of your html markup:

```
$('button').click(function() { //clear inputs });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is because you are setting your variables to be the string values of the elements, rather than the jQuery objects containing the elements.

Try this:

```
var $contact_title = $('#contact_title');
var $contact_summary = $('#bbcode');
$contact_title.val('');
$contact_summary.val('');
```

Or alternatively;

```
$('#contact_title').val('');
$('#bbcode').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable ($contact_title) contains the text, not the actual DOM-element, from what I can tell. If you change it to

```
$('#contact_title').val('');
```

You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the same syntax that you used while getting the values from those filed. 
try:

```
$('#contact_title').val('');
$('#bbcode').val('');
```

Answer (score 1):

In js fiddle easier to write/read javascript code. Here is an answer. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7RFYx/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
    var $contact_title = $('#contact_title');
    var $contact_summary = $('#bbcode');
    var $contact_summary_val = $contact_summary.val();
    var $contact_title_val = $contact_title.val();
    $contact_title.val('');
    $contact_summary.val('');
});
```